# Generate a sequence number (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3) within groups of different length

Tags: r, sequence, seq

I have a data frame with a column "Tag", here with four different levels. I need help to create the "Seq" column, a sequence generated from the "Tag" Column:

```
df <- data.frame(Tag = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                 Seq = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 )
```

Each "Tag" should be divided into 3 sub-groups defined by "Seq". We need to generate runs of 1, 2, and 3, with a total length of that of each "Tag". Thus,  the length of each run of 1, 2, and 3 respectively depends on length of each "Tag".

Note that the length each "Tag" differs. For example, Tag 1 is of length 31, and has a "Seq" `10` times `1`, `10` times `2`, and `11` times `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, Tag 1 is 31 while tag 2 is 32. Looking at the code below, the first number (1) will always be of lesser length than the next two (2,3). I used a ceiling process to come up with this. There is no clear criteria on what the code should do if the number is eg 31/3.. should it give a length of 10, 10, 11? or even 9, 11,11 will be fine? The code gives a 9, 11, 11 length:

```
 ec=table(Tag)
 unlist(mapply(function(x,y)rep(c(1,2,3),c(x,y,y)),ec-2*ceiling(ec/3),ceiling(ec/3)))
```

To check the outputted results, save the results in a variable.. `d=mapply(...`
then do   `sapply(d,table)`.
Hope this will be of help.

Comment: #Onyambu ,i appreciate your code ...to get the result in vector form we have unlist the result d ,please do edit to unlist ,This will be helpful to others also ...Thank you  And Can you please explain the code especially `c(x,y,y)` Would be helpful for understanding

Comment: And about you Comment that number 1 is always less then number 2 ...it can be less also and it can be more as well there isnt any such condition...and about length (10,10,11) or (9,11,11) doesn't matter with the order , But it should distribute itself with 3 levels ..thank you for the support

Comment: `c(x,y,y)` simply means `rep(1,x),rep(2,y) and rep(3,y)`. Hope the link : [how to use mapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html)  will be of help. Thank you

Comment: Since I used `ceiling`, The number of times 1 will be repeated ie `x times` is less than the number of times  2 and 3 will be repeated ie `y times`. you can use `floor` instead of `ceiling` and the length of `1` will always be greater than that of `2 and 3` when the length of Tag i is not divisible by 3

Answer (score 1):

```
ave(Tag, Tag, FUN = function(x){sort(rep(x = 1:3, length.out = length(x)))})
```

---

Explanation: For each level of "Tag" (`ave(Tag, Tag, ...`): `rep`eat each level of "Seq" (`x = 1:3`) to the length of the subset of "Tag" (`length.out = length(x)`). `sort` the numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your solution , i have a query about this is , `if the length of Tag is not divisible by 3 ` still this code will work ? Because with divisible of 3 it sure its gonna work very sure , Please do reply

Comment: @NabiShaikh Well, why didn't you just try it yourself? ;) Here's a smaller example: `rep(1:3, length.out = 2)`, `rep(1:3, length.out = 3)`; `rep(1:3, length.out = 4)`; `rep(1:3, length.out = 5)`.